# Does it make sense to find 2160p/1080p version of old movies?

Tags: video, resolution, download, bittorrent

Sometimes we encounter old movies labeled with 2160p or 1080p on the internet and they are indeed as large in size as more recent high-resolution movies.

But does it make sense or is it meaningful to find such versions? I think at least there was no commercial 4k video one or two decades ago, not sure about 1080p.

Comment: Really not sure this is on topic here. [movies.se] or even [photography.se] might be a better fit. Don't forget that 70mm or even 35mm celluloid can be converted to astonishingly high resolution, it depends when the digitisation was done.

Comment: FILM is an analog medium - the non-existence of 2K/4K/8K etc digital formats when the film was shot is completely irrelevant. Note: "one or two decades ago" is in the 2000's ... you calling them old makes me feel like a dinosaur!!!

Comment: For comparison, Dunkirk, shot on 70mm IMAX is claimed to match 18K.

Comment: Digital and film stock are two different things. Lack of HD video decades ago doesn’t mean film from decades ago wouldn’t benefit from an HD transfer. HD collects more data and details and can help make clearer copies of old films.

Answer (score 2):

35 mm monochrome film, e.g., [Panatomic-X](http://www.alexluyckx.com/blog/2018/09/17/classic-film-review-kodak-panatomic-x/), could capture the equivalent of [~100Mp/frame](https://cool.culturalheritage.org/videopreservation/library/estimating_historic_image_resolution_v9.pdf)*. **If** the original film is sharp, and  **if** it were scanned with care, it would correspond to  approximately about **three times** [8k standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8K_resolution), ~33Mp. That is, the information in the B&W film **exceeds** the  highest current video standards by a factor of **three**.

That said, the question is vaguely worded, because it depends on *exactly what the source is* and *with what care it's converted to digital format*, so an answer is SWAG.

* <sub>35mm x 24 mm / (25.4 mm/in)<sup>2</sup> * (8,636 pixels/in)<sup>2</sup> = 97,104,000 pixels</sub>

Comment: ... and all this is very theoretical as you have not included a single word on the optics involved. I'd say, from personal experience, that all "megapixels" above 25-30 or such are prone to reveal more about the lens used than actual detail of the subject. This at least unless you're using the very highest quality lenses. And yet further, what about "upscayle" and similar techniques to enlarge images...